# Как перевести на транслит?

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Как мне перевести строку на транслит? Например: БИТ1-15 -> BIT1-15 
Может уже есть алгоритм какой-то или библиотека?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А чем вас не устраивает что-то вроде такого:

```
HashMap<string, string> alph = new Map<string, string>;

aplh.put("а", "а");
aplh.put("b", "б");
aplh.put("c", "ц");
aplh.put("d", "д");
aplh.put("th", "с");
....

string str = "БИТ1-15";

for(int i=0; i<alph.keySet.size(); i++)
  str = str.replace(alph.keySet[i], alph[alph.keySet[i]]);

return str;
```

Comment: Думаю, что будет очень много контр примеров.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это наиболее простое решение. Не спорю, что можно придумать что-то более умное и правильное, но для того примера, который привел автор, должно работать нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Советую глянуть [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/250885/). Да, там на js, но код понятен. Можно легко портировать на Java